# Стиль для checkbox

Tags: checkbox, html, css

Как для checkbox применить красный border и сделать галочку красным цветом?

Comment: Самому чекбоксу - никак. Но сам чекбокс можно ужать до ширины в ноль пикселей, скажем, а его тображение реализовать с помощью :before.

Answer (score 2):

Я вам дам "крутую" наводку, а дальше сами, Ок? ( http://jsfiddle.net/4qqjhtw7/ )

```
input { display: none; }
input + i { /* some style */ }
input:checked + i { /* some style */ }

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <i></i>
    Checkbox Label
</label>
```

Единственный минус - для IE8 нужно скриптовать и "вручную" навешивать класс, от IE9+ работает прекрасно! Для полноты ответа скрипт для "отсталых" браузеров такой: http://jsfiddle.net/vtdb8rh3/1/

Comment: в ie8 это работает, просто вместо display: none надо делать postion:fixed;left -1000px; как у меня, в соседнем примере.

Comment: К сожалению нет ( http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Achecked ) IE8 не понимает `:checked`

Comment: в понед проверю, вроде как раз недавно я это использовал и тестил в IE8 и единственное, что ему не нравилось, это display:none для input в label.

Comment: а точно, мне не стиль нужен был, а чтобы просто click по label срабатывал.